# GLKViewControllerDelegate getting blocked

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, mapkit, glkit

I have a GLKViewController to handle some OpenGL drawing.  I have the `glkView:drawInRect` and `update` method both implemented and have the `preferredFramesPerSecond` property set to 30 (the default).

The problem is that the delegate methods stop firing when the user interacts with other part of the app.  The two cases that I have seen this happen on is when the user scrolls a UITableView or interacts with a MKMapView.

Is there a way to make sure these delegates *always* fire, regardless of what the rest of the app is doing.  The only time I want these to stop is when the app enters the background (which is does automatically).

Comment: There is not any realavent code. In the `GLKViewController` init I set the `preferredFramesPerSecond` to 30.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for this is that during scrolling in a table view or map view the runloop is in `UITrackingRunLoopMode` which has a higher priority than the default mode. This prevents some events from firing in order to guarantee a high scrolling performance.

To solve your problem you must set up your own rendering loop instead of relying on the `GLKViewController`.

- First set `enableSetNeedsDisplay` of the `GLKView` to `NO` (should be set automatically when using GLKViewController).
- set `preferredFramesPerSecond` to 0 (or maybe 1) to disable the rendering loop of `GLKViewController` or don't use GLKViewController at all
- Import the QuartzCore framework: `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
- create a `CADisplayLink` and schedule it in `NSRunLoopCommonModes`:

```
CADisplayLink* displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(render:)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

- optional: set the frameInterval of displayLink to 2 (= half the framerate)
- the render method:

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {
    GLKView* view = (GLKView*)self.view;
    [view display];
}
```

I haven't tested this, so tell me if it works!

Comment: This does work. I was looking for a way where I didn't have to do this, but I think you are right that this is the only way to go.

Comment: For some reason, this causes my framerate to go down to 2 seconds per frame!

Comment: @JosephHumfrey check the frameInterval property of CADisplayLink (default = 1). Maybe you have set it to 30 by mistake? The framerate should be equal to `1 / (displayLink.frameInterval * displayLink.duration)`