# Why does my NSTimer selector never fire? Is it because it's in GLKitViewController instead of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer, glkit

At a certain state in the program, I call a method with this as the body:

```
self.timeStartedDisplayingTime = [NSDate date];
self.stopButton.enabled = YES;

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I've verified that this method is indeed called.

However, the corresponding selector's body:

```
NSTimeInterval elapsedTimeDisplayingECG = [self.timeStartedDisplayingECG timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
self.elapsedTimeValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", elapsedTimeDisplayingECG];
```

Is never called. I've put a breakpoint on it and it's never reached. Why is this exactly? It's in a GLKitViewController instead if that's relevant.

Comment: Did you verify that the code that launches the timer gets called?

Comment: Take a look at this thread, this might point to a real reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080932/glkviewcontrollerdelegate-getting-blocked

Answer (score -1):

Your timer gets thrown away right after creating it. You need to retain is somewhere.

Define a property

`@property (strong) NSTimer *myTimer;`

and assign your timer to this:

`self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(updateElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Comment: timers are retained by the runloop till fired or invalidate so this isn't it